# Excel - opening file creates 'dummy' task bar icon

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I just upgraded to Excel 2016 (Windows 7), and notice that when I open an excel file, I get two icons in the Task Bar.  One is the file, which is correct, but the other (when clicked) just goes to a blank workbook:

[image: two icons, "dummy" is the one on the left]

and when I click the left one, it's just a blank application, not even a workbook:

[image: null]

However, if I close Excel, and just start a new instance (clicking a shortcut link), it opens a single blank workbook.  I can then File --> Open, open a file, and have one icon in the task bar (which is what it should do).

When there are the two icons, I can't just close that empty application window, it asks me if I want to close the file I opened.

Why are two icons being created when opening a file from Windows Explorer?

Another quirk.  I opened Excel, then opened a workbook from within Excel.  This creates a single task bar icon (yay!).  Now, when I close that workbook (<kbd>CTRL+W</kbd>), it closes *but* the "empty" Excel application window opens and remains there.  How come it doesn't close my Excel Application when I close the last open workbook?  If I click the "X" to close, then it correctly closes the last workbook and the application.  <kbd>CTRL+W</kbd> does not.

Thanks for any ideas. Perhaps it's something to do with my `Personal.xlsb` macros/workbook?

Comment: I edited the question for you. I've never used 2016 on windows but I suspect your thoughts are correct.

Comment: @Raystafarian - thanks!  I'm new to it, testing it out to see if we should go with it, and this is quite a peculiar bug that I'd think they saw pretty quickly in testing.  I'm trying to see if it happens any other way, but so far, only when I open a file from Windows Explorer does this happen. I can open Excel, which defaults to a new `Book1`, then File--> Open, and it keeps only the single icon.

Answer (score 2):

I  have the same issue and my solution is as follows:

1) location personal.xlsb (C:\Users\"User"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART) where "User is your username"

2) Cut and paste personal.xlsb to the desktop and remane to something else. i used personal_actual.xlsb so i know this is my actual personal.xlsb file that i want

3) open excel fresh from the start menu i.e. not another excel file

4) record a macro and save it to the personal.xlsb location (make sure you do something - anything - for the macro to record. this creates a new personal.xlsb file in the XLSTART folder

5) save and close excel (save the personal.xlsb and not the book1 file)

6) right click-open the new and the desktop perxonal.xlsb & personal_actual.xlsb files

7) copy the macro from the personal_actual.xlsb file into the new personal.xlsb file

8) save and close the new personal.xlsb file

You may want to hold on to the original personal.xlsb file just in case. you also may have to re-link any button you have on the ribbon to the macros in the new personal.xlsb

Hope this helps